# How to change values in certain columns according to certain rule in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe looks like this:

    `col1    col2
0   A       A60
1   B       B23
2   C       NaN`

The data from is read from a csv file. Suppose I want to change each non-missing value of 'col2' to its prefix (i.e. 'A' or 'B'). How could I do this without writing a `for` loop?

The expected output is 

    `col1    col2
0   A       A
1   B       B
2   C       NaN`

Answer (score 1):

.str[:1] just returns the first character

```
d = {'col1': ['A', 'B','C'], 'col2': ['A32', 'B60',np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str[:1]
df
```

out:

```
    col1    col2
0   A       A
1   B       B
2   C       NaN
```

Comment: How would i do this if there are missing values in 'col2'?

Comment: What is the expected output? How do you want to handle the NaN? Currently, it would just leave the NaN as is.

Comment: Just leave NaN as is

Comment: Then you do not need to change anything. It leaves the NaN intact. I will update my answer to show outputs.

Comment: What version of pandas, numpy and python are you using. Make sure in your data that NaN is actually Not a Number (numpy.nan) and not a string: 'NaN'

Comment: I read a pandas dataframe from a csv file. I don't know what type of NaN  it is.

Comment: I cannot duplicate the problem after testing with a csv file. `pd.__version__` is `0.22.0`

Answer (score 0):

You can also your pandas `replace` function directly on the column.

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A','B','C'], 'col2':['A60','B23',np.nan]})

# remove numbers from col2
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.replace('\d+','')

print(df)

  col1 col2
0   A   A
1   B   B
2   C   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `isnull()`:

`df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[0] if not pd.isnull(x) else x)`

Comment: I think it is same as `df['col2'] = df['col2'].str[0]`

Comment: pandas functions `.str` worrking with `NaN`s perfectly, so not necessary if-else if `NaN`s

Comment: I tried ``df['col2'] = df['col2'].str[0]``, but ends up with 'n' instead of ``NaN``